# On a USB that has been formatted as a windows recovery USB, can i use the spare space for file storage/transfer?

Tags: windows-10, usb, data-recovery

I just created a recovery disk for my laptop w/a 16Gb recovery SanDisk Ultra Fit thumb drive and there is still 4.8GB of free space.

Can i put other files on the USB drive, and will it still function as a recovery disk?

TIA,
oldwolf

Comment: I tested this and you can store additional files on it without affecting the drive from acting as a recovery disc.

Answer (score 0):

You can put more files on there (which you could've found out yourself).

The drive will still function as a recovery disk, whether you have other files on there or not.

Edit: I can't comment so: This is not an issue, it's a question.